# BoxCollider2D Bounds in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a BoxCollider2D variable, called `Bounds`, I was trying to use `Bounds.bounds.min`, but  it does not recognize  `bounds` and thus I am not able to get the extremes of BoxCollider2D Bounds.

I am using Unity 4.3, Is the functionality not available in the version?

Comment: `Bounds` is also a class name. This may be the cause of your problem. Please add the non-working code to your question if you still need help.

Comment: @Leosori : Oh, No that was not really the problem :)

Comment: Recall too that until they fix it, you can often just use a thin "ordinary, old-fashioned" 3D collider.  So you can then use "bounds".  Performance is rarely an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They say Bounds for Collider2D will be available in future updates.

For now, you must calculate bounds in script. [Here](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/physics2d-bounds-and-extents.211486/) you may find a fine solution.

Comment: Yes, I realized that the fix has been made in 4.5 only.Thank you for the link. It's helpful :)

Comment: development gem: Sorry about this bump after long, but what if I am using it with main Camera where I do not have any colliders or renderers?

Comment: Do you need bounds for camera in 2D?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
gameObject.renderer.bounds
```

And from the bounds you can achieve what you want.

Comment: renderer bounds != collider bounds